# clipping background image

Tags: html, css

I have a large png file that I am using as background image file for my various elements using css. I can use that image when I know the width and height of the element, like

```
<div id="play-btn"></div>
.play-btn{
    background: url(../images/bigImage.png) no-repeat 203px 415px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

how to use that bigImage as background when I dont want to provide width/height of the elemtn, like

```
<div id="star-icon">star on left</div>
.star-icon{
    background: /*How I will use bigImage here on where star is at location 50,50*/,
    padding: 5px 0 5px 60px;
}
```

Comment: in order to use sprites, you have to constrain the output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use negative left and top, it moves the bgImage in that direction so it displays starting at 50px.

```
background: url(../images/bigImage.png) no-repeat -50px -50px;
```